# Embedding HTML with <object>/<embed> introduces BODY and HTML tags

Tags: html

I need to embed a sub-HTML into another HTML. I am using 2 approaches,

```
<object type="text/html" data="test.html"></object>
```

OR

```
<embed type="text/html" src="test.html">
```

But this inserts HEAD and BODY tags, even though my sub-page doesn't have them. By sub-page test.html only contains the following and nothing else

```
<div>
    <p>Test Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Resulting DOM:

[image]

This could introduce HTML validation issues and spacing. Do people use these approaches at all? Is there a way to embed without the extra HEAD/BODY?

**NOTE Cannot use iframes**, they are outdated & introduce other problems.

Comment: `iframe`s perhaps?

Comment: Sorry can't use iframes. They're outdated and introduce a host of other problems.

Comment: @geneb. “outdated”? According to whom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have varied options to choose from, having iframes aside, you can:

- use a javascript framework/lib which gives you the option to load the "sub-page" via Ajax, for example in jQuery, the [**`.load()`**](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.
- use server-side language, i.e in PHP you can just use [**`include`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), [**`include_once`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php), [**`require`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php), or [**`require_once`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php).
- [HTML Imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports), `<link rel="import" href="path-to-file/filename.html">`, are the best and IMHO this should've been implemented long time ago, but the problem is it lacks wide browsers support, only Chrome and Opera currently, [caniuse.com/imports](http://caniuse.com/#feat=imports)

Comment: Yes I ended up using JS .load() on the DIV element. Safest choice.